# HTML : Is there any way to show images in a textarea?

Tags: html, image, textarea, thumbnails, photo

So I want to show `image thumbnails` too in the `<textarea>` along with text. If you know a javascript solution that's perfect too(if possible in vanilla JS).

Like this:

```
__________________
|Hello World     |
|  _______       |
|  | Img |       |
|  |     |       |
|  |_____|       |
|Hello again.    |
|  _______       |
|  | Img2|       |
|  |     |       |
|  |_____|       |
|________________|
```

As I know and seen in a div or anything what has `contentEditable="true"` allows image too but, allows many other HTML tags and a lots of things what I don't want :|

I want just `text` and `images`.

Answer (score 74):

Use a div with contentEditable attribute which acts like a textarea. That's how wysiwyg editors are created.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">Type here. You can insert images too
  <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCze-mfukcuvzKk7Ilj2zQ0CS6PbOkq7ZhRInnNd1Yz3TQzU4e&t=1" />
</div>
```

Comment: The example does really strange things if I try to insert newlines.  In Chrome at least.

Comment: @aroth Looks like it's because every newline creates a new `div` element, and every `div` has width, height, and border properties.

Comment: the answer doesn't address his question. Is it possible? if not then please state so then proceed with additional information

Answer (score 11):

I understand you want to edit text and pictures but... why does it have to be inside a textarea? Such control is designed to hold plain text. There're many HTML editors written in JavaScript:

- http://ckeditor.com/
- http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/
- http://www.openwebware.com/
- http://www.unverse.net/whizzywig-cross-browser-html-editor.html
- http://www.htmlarea.com/
- ...

Comment: Because I don't want to build a complex editor, as I said I want just `text` and `photos`.

Comment: The user's question was specifically regarding a text-area.

Comment: @DustinOprea - That's impossible. Period. The `<textarea>` element can only hold plain text, not other nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, it's not possible, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @thomasmalt , then what do you suggest how should I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to use textarea with images to display your content to the user, or do you want to use textarea in a form where the user provides text and uploads images?

Answer (score 1):

you can use css to set an background image for textarea, and js to set the text

Comment: I don't want a background for the textarea, I want to have images inside the textarea. Or do you mean to hack the textarea with a background so it would look like there is an image inside the textarea? If yes then that's not a good idea because there will be multiple images, and can be updated and deleted too. Edited my question to illustrate it.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use images in a textarea, neither a background-image set with CSS nor an img element.

Comment: I don't know what you wanna do, but you can insert anything but plain text inside the textarea. While you do can use CSS to set a background image for an textarea, if you wanna change it, you can then use javascript to change the background.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">Type here. You can insert images too
  <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCze-mfukcuvzKk7Ilj2zQ0CS6PbOkq7ZhRInnNd1Yz3TQzU4e&t=1" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script (ideally in PHP) which checks if there is unwanted element (another than `<p>` or `<img>`).

Then you can send user back to "form" and let him to fill again or you can delete the whole unwanted tags.