# How to edit image's property when using Html.TextAreaFor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, asp.net-controls

I'm using TextAreaFor Html helper for editing content. Now I insert an image into the box and want to modify it's properties such as width, height.. but I dont see any buttons or context menu help me manage this. How can I figure out to enable this feature?

I know some other tools implementing this feature like [RadEditor of Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx). But I just want to use Html helper here.

Really appriciate for any suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML : Is there any way to show images in a textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793090/html-is-there-any-way-to-show-images-in-a-textarea)

Comment: I dont think they are similar because I am working on Html helper of ASP.NET MVC 3, and I do not really understand what that question wants.

Comment: Of course, they are similar. The helper produces a textarea and you can't put images in a textarea.  You need to find a different solution.

Comment: OK. I found the solution. Thanks

Comment: Could you post here what solution did you found so that it will also be  helpful to other people who will encounter the same problem.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to implement a WYSIWYG editor then you should try something like:

KendoUI: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/index.html

or

TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/