# How can i display the video to be uploaded in the taxtarea where the user enter some text from

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a text area where the user is expected to enter some text and after upload videos.here i need the videos selected to be displayed with the text input.i will so gland if some help me. Thanks

```
//here is my form

<form role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    <!--<i class="icon-facetime-video"></i>-->


                                     <!-- <span class="btn btn-file btn-success" input type="file" name="file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>-->

            <!-- <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">-->

<textarea class="fileupload-preview  thumbnail" name="post_content" class="form-control" rows="3" style="border-left:thin; border-left-color:#fff; border-right:thin; border-right-color:#fff" placeholder="<?php echo "  What is really on your mind,", $_SESSION['first_name']; ?>?"></textarea>


</div>  


                        <input class="fileupload-new" style="margin-left:75%; padding-top:5px;" type="file" value="Uplaod Videos" name="upd"/>

                       <span class="btn btn-file btn-success" input type="file" name="file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><input type="file" name="profile_image"/></span>
```

//above is my textarea

//and this my submit button

I have tried but nothing is appearing in the text area.

```
<input type="submit" name="post" value="POST" style="color:blue; margin-right:3%; float:right;"/>


              </form>
```

Comment: I think your best bet is a contenteditable div, rather than a textarea

Comment: i need help please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793090/html-is-there-any-way-to-show-images-in-a-textarea. This discusses images, but has the idea you're looking for.

Comment: how can i make the placeholder hidden.when its there but do not need to be deleted in order to enter his data.

Comment: i mean the user should not first delete it

Comment: ok. thanks so much for your help.let me try to use it sir.