# Add image between lines of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I want to be able to click on a word in the value of a textarea and then add a small cross image under the word that lies in the line spacing. And then whenever the user types in more i would like for the cross to stick under the word

Comment: share your code

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us the code you are working on?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: This would be a huge work to do, since a textarea contains plain text only. It would be easier to achieve this by using a content editable div or pre element instead of a textarea.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793090/html-is-there-any-way-to-show-images-in-a-textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML : Is there any way to show images in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793090/html-is-there-any-way-to-show-images-in-a-textarea)

Comment: Sounds like a WYSIWYG editor should work?