# How could I upload text and file at textarea in html?

Tags: html

How could I upload text at textarea in html????
I'm doing with eGovFrameWork.

┌───────────────┐
│hello world!!! upload.png│             <-textarea
└───────────────┘

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HelloWorld</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="10" readonly></textarea><br>
            <label for="jb-input-text">
            <input type="text" size="39"></label><br>
                <button class="favorite styled" type="button">upload</button><br>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you wanna put the values of `text` and `file` in `textarea`, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting image inside textarea isn't possible, but it can be done with contenteditable div:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607496/12425881